Error: Cannot find module 'metro/src/lib/TerminalReporter' when building Expo app in a monorepo
I am encountering an issue when trying to build my Expo app using npx expo run:ios in a Turborepo monorepo setup. The error message I receive is:
Error: Cannot find module 'metro/src/lib/TerminalReporter'
Require stack:
- @expo/cli/build/src/start/server/metro/TerminalReporter.js
- @expo/cli/build/src/start/server/metro/MetroTerminalReporter.js
- @expo/cli/build/src/start/server/metro/instantiateMetro.js
- @expo/cli/build/src/start/server/metro/MetroBundlerDevServer.js
- @expo/cli/build/src/start/server/DevServerManager.js
- @expo/cli/build/src/run/startBundler.js
- @expo/cli/build/src/run/ios/runIosAsync.js
- @expo/cli/build/src/run/ios/index.js
- @expo/cli/build/bin/cli
- expo/bin/cli

This error appears in any project that is part of a monorepo. However, when I run npx expo run:ios in a standard Expo repository (without monorepo setup), everything works perfectly fine. Additionally, running npx expo start --ios in the monorepo setup does work without any issues.
Here are the steps I followed to set up the monorepo, as per the Expo Monorepos guide.
Has anyone else encountered this issue or can provide guidance on how to resolve it? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
I have tried deleting and reinstalling node_modules without any success.
